# Netsuite query with WITH clause

Tags: sql, oracle, netsuite, suiteql

Any clue why the following works?

```
with tbl as (select itemprice.item as stock
             from itemprice)
select stock
from tbl
```

and

```
with tbl as (select item.id as stock
             from item)
select stock
from tbl
```

does not?

Comment: What error message are you getting? `item` and `itemprice` seem to be different tables?

Comment: Doesn't work _how_?

Comment: is Item a table, and if so, is column name "id" found in it?

Comment: yes item and itemprice are two different tables, item.id = itemprice.item to be precise, the error i get is unsupported search.